# PostgreSQL `initdb` permission denied with `rwx` permissions and logged as postgres

Tags: postgresql, credentials, postgresql-initdb

I want to set up a PostgreSQL database but `initdb` hits an authentication error. I seem to be doing as described in docs.

1. I log in as *postgres* user with `doas -u postgres -s` (AFAIK it's same as `su - postgres`)
2. `cd` to `/home/user/A/B/postgres`.
3. `stat .` yields

> Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: (  965/postgres)   Gid: (  965/postgres)

4. `id` yields

> uid=965(postgres) gid=965(postgres) groups=965(postgres)

5. Running `initdb -D /home/user/A/B/data` results in an error with:

> could not change directory to "/home/user/A/B/postgres": Permission denied
>
> The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
> This user must also own the server process.
>
> The database cluster will be initialized with locale "C".
> The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "SQL_ASCII".
> The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
>
> Data page checksums are disabled.
>
> initdb: error: could not access directory "/home/user/A/B/postgres/data": Permission denied

This or similar error is hit with or without the directory `data` created beforehand and also using both relative and absolute paths. The folders A and B in the path are not owned by *postgres*.

I'm using **postgresql 13.4-6** on manjaro with doas for authentication and sudo uninstalled.

Comment: 'The folders A and B in the path are not owned by postgres.' would be your problem. The OS user `postgres` does not have the permissions to traverse `"/home/user/A/B` to get to `/data`.

Comment: **Solution**: Indeed path traversing is the problem. I added execute permissions for others in folders up in the path and it solves the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I thought about that but dismissed as it didn't work with relative paths as well. Shouldn't relative path resolution work? 
In the end I don't think I'm doing anything strange? It should be possible to create database somewhere deep into directory tree without any 'global' permission changes?


EDIT: Apparently this is how path resolution works as checked with various other commands.

Comment: It would be a big security hole if someone could bypass all upper level permissions in a path to get a lower directory they have permissions on.